# PostgreSQL query with variable result column

Tags: postgresql

Hoping i'm missing something simple here, and saying it clearly..
I have a table that i need to join to 1 of 2 possible other tables, depending on user input of the id found in the primary table.

```
t1:
primary_id | t2_id | t3_id
--------------------------  
         1 |     x |  null  
         2 |  null |     y
```

---

```
t2:  
id | value
----------
 x |     a
```

---

```
t3:  
id | value
----------
 y |     b
```

I want to do the following in a single query:

```
select primary_id, t2_value from t1, t2
where t1.t2_id=t2.id

or 

select primary_id, t3_value from t1, t3
where t1.t3_id=t3.id
```

here's the full join:

```
    with t1 as (select * from t1),
    t2 as (select * from t2),
    t3 as (select * from t3),

    select * from
    t1
    left join
    t2
    on t1.t2_id=t2.id
    left join
    t3
    on t1.t3_id=t3.id
 where t1.t2_id is not null
```

when i run this, i'd like to get back just t1 and t2 columns, not t3..
please and thank you!

Comment: It seems like you could use the `UNION ALL` operator, it will add the records from your different parts of your query on the same columns, refer to [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_union.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COALESCE()`:

```
select t1.primary_id, 
  coalesce(t1.t2_id, t1.t3_id) id,
  coalesce(t2.value, t3.value) "value"
from t1
left join t2 on t1.t2_id=t2.id
left join t3 on t1.t3_id=t3.id
where t1.t2_id is not null
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kVKBD8bqaLN7gUfcVbApVA/1).
Results:

```
| primary_id | id  | value |
| ---------- | --- | ----- |
| 1          | x   | a     |
```

If you change the condition to:

```
where t1.t3_id is not null
```

you will get:

```
| primary_id | id  | value |
| ---------- | --- | ----- |
| 2          | y   | b     |
```

Comment: Thank you @forpas. to clarify, my problem is that t2 and t3 columns aren't 1:1- they are different from each other. coalescing them would be incorrect.. t2.value isn't the same result as t3.value, also t2 would have more columns to return than t3. any other options?

Comment: If so why did you post sample data that have nothing to do with your requirement?